# how to multi ref in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to ref two documents in one property, i have been checking the oficial documentation but i didn't get the solution...

At the moment i am trying this...

```
items: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: ['items','users']
}],
```

In the documentation they mention refPath... but i could not populate both models... any solution for this?

// LINK TO DOCUMENTATION
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref

Comment: Just making sure you know this, with `refPath`, you can configure what model Mongoose uses for each document. You can't populate from two models for a single document.

Comment: yes.. so i think that when you say that i cant populate from two models... it means that i cant do it at the same time right?

Comment: you can change formate of items and make it items: [{ id: {}, onModel: {} }]

Comment: @SergioCano the `model` which will be populated with for a `field` can depend on another `field`'s value(which will be a **string** containing the name of the `model`).

Comment: @SergioCano also you have to use `refPath` instead of `ref` with a value containing the name of the field(in the host document itself) which will be containing the `model` name to populate. If it's hard to understand then most probably because of my english.

Comment: @SumanKundu, hehe don't worry man, i understood, but the concept is a bit hard to understand, thank you for your comments

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass refs in arrays. Here is the simple solution:

**Mongoose Model (Report.js):**
You can clearly see that I did not pass any **ref** to my Model but still, you can use multiple refs in post/get APIs. I will show you next.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const reportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    reportFrom : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        require: true,
    },
    reportTo: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        require: true,
    },
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("report", reportSchema);
```

Above "**reportTo**" means the Id of someone post whom the user is going to report or the id of user profile whom the user is going to report. Means "**reportTo**" may be an ID of User Profile or Post. So, if "**reportTo**" contains user Id then I have to refer to **users** collection but if "**reportTo**" contains post Id then I have to refer to **posts** collection. So, how I can use two refs. I will simply pass **type** query from postman to tell which ref to go either posts or users. See below my API request:

**APIs file (reports.js)**

```
const reports = req.query.type === "Post" ? await Report.find({reportTo: req.params.id}).populate({
                path: 'reportFrom', // attribute name of Model
                model: "User", // name of model from where you want to populate
                select: "name profilePicture", // get only user name & profilePicture
            }).populate({
                path: 'reportTo', // attribute name of Model
                model: "Post",
            }).sort({ _id: -1 })

            : req.query.type === "Profile" ? await Report.find({reportTo: req.params.id}).populate({
                path: 'reportFrom', // attribute name of Model
                model: "User",
                select: "name profilePicture",
            }).populate({
                path: 'reportTo', // attribute name of Model
                model: "User",
                select: "name profilePicture",
            })
            .sort({ _id: -1 })
            : null 

            return res.status(200).json(reports);
```

See the line 7 & 15, you can clearly see how I use two different refs for same attribute. In first case, **reportTo** is refered to **Post** Model & in second case **reportTo** is refered to **User** Model.